# Accessing Class Variable in Independent Class Python2.7.1

Tags: python, class, class-variables

I have a question concerning class variables in Python.

I am trying to code a simple Attack class for an RPG, and I need in this class to access variables from my Weapon class and my Character Class, yet all three have no inheritance relationship to one another. And I can't find help online due to all the threads being on inheritance.

Here are the code samples of each class:

```
class Character(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, hp, image, speed, x, y):
        super(Character, self).__init__()
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect().move(x, y) #initial placement
        self.hp = hp

class Weapon(Item): #Parent class item is a sprite class
    def __init__(self, name, value, image, x, y, dmg):
        super(Weapon, self).__init__(name, value, image, x, y)
        self.dmg = dmg


class Attack(object):
    def __init__(self, Weapon, Character):
        self.Weapon = Weapon
        self.Character = Character      
    self.Character.hp -= self.Weapon.dmg
```

UPDATE ##### Indentation rectified

```
class Attack(object):
    def __init__(self, Weapon, Character):
        self.Weapon = Weapon
        self.Character = Character      
        self.Character.hp -= self.Weapon.dmg
```

When I try to run my program I get the following error:

```
  File "classes.py", line 136, in <module>
    class Attack(object):

  File "classes.py", line 141, in Attack
    self.Character.hp -= self.Weapon.dmg

NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Any idea on how I could access the hp variable from my Character class inside my Attack class ? Ultimately I will also need to access the dmg variable of the Weapon class inside the Attack class.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think there's much point in making Attack a class. Why not just have an attack() function?

Comment: I was just wondering about this... Should I be better of with classes for things like characters, items, inventories etc ...  would an attack method in the Character class using variables from the Weapon class and another Character be doable and easier to use. I will try it out.

Comment: Removing your indentation mistake isn't a good practice. Think about people who are watching your question, now they can't understand it.

Comment: You should let your question as is. But if you think it is too trivial, you can delete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a problem in your indentation of `self.Character.hp -= self.Weapon.dmg`. This code should work:

```
class Attack(object):
    def __init__(self, Weapon, Character):
        self.Weapon = Weapon
        self.Character = Character      
        self.Character.hp -= self.Weapon.dmg
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I am new to using Stack Overflow... would it be good practice to delete this question as it was a simple indentation error ?

Comment: You can decide to delete your question if you want. But nobody downvotes it so that means it has an interest.